# How to calculate the inverse of non-central f distribution in python?

Tags: python, math, distribution

I'm trying to use the functions from here to calculate the inverse of the cdf of the noncentral F distribution

`scipy.special import ncfdtr,ncfdtri, ncfdtridfd, ncfdtridfn,ncfdtrinc`'

I'm using

- `2` and `5-2=3` as the degree of freedom
- `5/ (0.001042**2 )` as the nc, which I think should be correct.
- `1-0.0027=0.9973` as the p for the, where I think it should be the output of c.d.f.

But i tried each function but all i get is `nan` and `0.0`.

I also tried using the excel version from [here](http://www.real-statistics.com/chi-square-and-f-distributions/noncentral-f-distribution/), with `p=0.0027`, but i cant get the same value when using python

`print(ncfdtri( dfd, dfn, ncp, a )) = 264386.8371546744`, when it is 259533.97396 at excel

`print(ncfdtri(dfn, dfd, ncp, a )) = 496074.40359445167`, when it is 487951.32384 at excel

But when I tried using `a=1-0.0027`, which gives me `1e+100` for both, which i think its not an answer.

Can someone help me on this please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get inverse CDF you have to call Percent point function, aka PPF.

First, there are questions about your `nc` parameter - it is about 5,000,000, which makes very sharp step in the graph. So, code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import ncf

dfn = 2
dfd = 3
nc  = 5 / (0.001042**2) # 1.0

rv = ncf(dfn, dfd, nc) # RV of non-central F distribution

x = np.linspace(0.01, 0.99, 100) # for inverse CDF, [0...1] is proper X interval

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.plot(x, rv.ppf(x), 'r-', lw=5, alpha=0.6, label='ncf PPF(inv.CDF)')

plt.show()

print(rv.ppf(0.9973))
```

will produce graph

[image]

If you change `nc` to somewhat reasonable 1.0, you'll get graph

[image]

Anyway, here is code for inverse CDF (aka PPF) you've asked for. Last question is what is `0.9973 as the p` - the only parameters left are either scale or location. You could easily add it to `ncf(dfn, dfd, nc, loc, scale)` call.

UPDATE

Actually, if you messed up parameters such that `nc` is actually equal to 0.9973, then my second graph would be pretty much the answer to your question.

UPDATE II

Well, if `nc` is really about 5 million, then `print(rv.ppf(0.9973))` really produced output 1<sup>100</sup>. Look at the first graph and note number at top left corner.

Comment: I needed a single value for the answer, but this output made me more confused.

Comment: @DanielMana Well, if you REALLY wanted answer of CDF(0.9973) and your `nc` is about 5 million then 1^100 is the answer.

Comment: @DanielMana I've updated the answer, it prints 1^100

Comment: thanks, it works even though I don't understand what happened.

Comment: @DanielMana Well, it involves noncentral chi2, I believe, with something like `exp(-nc/2)` in denominator, which translates into exp(nc/2) in the nominator, which, in turn, for nc circa 5mlin translates into HUGE number you see.